# Is my ether on owned smart contract was locked forever?

Tags: ether

This is my first contract i deployed.
Please say no.

https://etherscan.io/address/0xa048481aea8e2582f2eb7745f6e6c04a5599863c#code

Comment: I can’t see a method to get your money back, you need to test your contract locally and then on a test chain before deploying it to mainnet :( and you need to remove the console logs ….

Comment: Thanks!You are right. I have reflected on that...